# Run htmlentities() on all submitted values through gravity forms

Tags: php, plugin-gravity-forms

I need a way to run through all submitted values throghh the htmlentities() filter in gravity forms. I am using the `gform_pre_submission` filter. I am successfuly able to find the type of field since we donot want to do this for URLS or file inputs. But I do not know how to actually grab the fields within the form object. Here's the code I am using.

```
add_action( 'gform_pre_submission', 'pre_submission_handler' );
public function pre_submission_handler( $form ) 
{
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
        if ($field->type !== 'fileupload') {
            /* Run the field through htmlentitites filter */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `htmlentities` is the sort of function you'd run on _output_, as part of escaping. Why do you need to run it on submission?

Comment: What do you mean by output? I want to run it on the values submitted within the form by the user

Comment: Well normally this function is something you'd run *right before* outputting into an HTML or XML document, to make sure it doesn't get interpreted as HTML. It's not something you would need to do when saving to the database.

Comment: We're hooking into the email through the hook 'gform_pre_send_email' I just need a way that the values entered by the user on the form are already escaped before they are access by the 'gform_pre_send_email' hook. I couldn't find a hierarchy of how hooks are executed on forms. Could you possibly guide me how

Comment: Gravity Forms doesn't already do this? I'd be surprised if Gravity Forms allowed unescaped HTML into notification emails.

Comment: No it does not. If I enter for example <test> in my first name field I get <test> in my email as well. Which was very strange for me as well

Comment: What's wrong with that? That means it's not being executed as HTML. If you enter `<strong>ABC</strong>DEF` in that field, do the first 3 characters appear bold in the email? Or do you just see what you wrote?

Comment: This is the prob we're facing. We cannot allow <test> as a valid field. Because when we render the XML out of it. <> are treated as open and end tags in an XML. So we need a way to filter them before. Would you know a way to do this?

Comment: Well as I was suggesting, `htmlentities()` should be being run when the XML is generated. Escaping should happen as late as possible. How and when are you creating this XML?

Comment: We already have an xml attached to each form which is sending out details entered within the form. What the extended module is doing is attaching the google UTM fields if present. Now when we grab the existing HTML from the email if it has <Fname><test><Fname> it only renders as </fname>